# Issue in Chrome, removing CSS with jQuery stays in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently working on a table application heavily coded in javascript using jQuery.

When you click on a td cell jQuery pushes 2px solid black to the border property. Then on blur I remove the style attribute with removeAttr to make it revert back to the stylesheet settings. Works fine in IE9, but when I test it in Chrome, the left border resizes, but stays black.

The only thing that seems to get rid of this is opening the console. When I blur with the console open the style tag removes so I don't understand why it's still rendering a black border on the left. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've made a video showing the problem I'm experiencing.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCmYNOO5u4I

Here's the code:

```
$("td.display").live('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}).live('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

The CSS is:

```
table TD.selected {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: Black;
}
```

Comment: what version of chrome are you using? Plus, would you mind trying add/remove class methods to achieve the same effect and see if it is repeated

Comment: You should post your code...Hard to tell without it.

Comment: Why not add & remove classes instead of messing with adding & removing the entire style attribute?

Comment: why don't you do `.css('border','2px solid #000')`  and revert to `.css('border','')` ?

Comment: Code was not all that complicated, this is it:
'$(this).css('border', '2px solid black');
$(this).removeAttr('style');'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using JavaScript to achieve this trivial effect, use CSS. The [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3ahover) pseudo-selector is [well-supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t14) in all modern browsers.

```
td.display:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

I have adjusted your selectors, since `<td>` elements are always contained in a `<table>` element.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKM7e/

---

## Update

This is one of the many table-css-related bugs in Chrome. A work-around is to initiate a re-render. To solve the issue, let Chrome render the page again. This fix should not activate in non-webkit browsers, so an additional variable is added.

I've also optimized your code, and replaced the deprecated `live` with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The new revision can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/9EJAKNRb).

```
// true if webkit, false otherwise
var isWebkit = !!$('<div style="-webkit-border-radius:1px">')[0].style.cssText.length;

$(document).on('blur', 'input.editCell', function () {
    var $thisParent = $(this).parent();      // <-- Optimizing by caching
    // Remove Highlight and bold around cell
    $thisParent.removeClass('selected');
    var colRow = $thisParent.attr('id').split('_');
    $('th:containsExactly(' + colRow[0] + ')').removeAttr('style');
    $('td.yAxis:containsExactly(' + colRow[1] + ')').removeAttr('style');
    // Change class back to display
    $thisParent.attr('class', 'display');
    // Take the entered value and put it in the cell
    $thisParent.html(this.value);
    // if(isFunction(this.value) === 'SUM')

    if (isWebkit) { // Fix for Webkit bug: render the table again
        // Without jQuery, for efficiency
        var style = document.getElementById('spreadsheetTable').style;
        style.color = '#111';                       //<--1. Change style 
        setTimeout(function(){style.color='';}, 4); //<--2. Fix
    }
});
```

Comment: It's actually not hovering, it's clicking, and once another cell is clicked the cell should return to normal state. Think of it like excel. I changed my code to mouseover and mouseleave to demonstrate my issue better.

For the record, I just added :hover to the CSS and the issue is actually still present.

Comment: @Dave Your changed code did not improve the demonstration... EDIT: Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on making my code more efficient, sadly the issue still remains. As for click vs mouse hover. If you read my question I clearly state "When you CLICK on a td cell jQuery pushes 2px solid black to the border property."

I also believe it did help my video, as i would have had to click twice and then clicked somewhere else to make my original code work. But as it stands, this isn't a javascript issue it's a CSS issue. Your original advice to add the :hover proves that.

Comment: @Dave Can you provide the real code? I can guess for your intentions, but that's a waste of time..

Comment: If you open up excel, and click on a cell, and then click on another cell that's my intentions. I don't know how my code will make it any clearer than that. I want a black border on a selected cell, just like excel. Microsoft Excel.

Comment: @Dave >_> But **what is your current code** (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)? You're struggling with the implementation of an *"Excel"-like* effect, but you didn't share your code. Ideally, post your current example at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I've uploaded basically my entire project, some things don't work as it's not connected to the server but you can at least see the problem I'm having.
http://www.2shared.com/file/r6gh5ejo/spreadsheet.html

Comment: @Dave Updated answer. It's a Chrome bug, I have seen similar Chrome-bugs before.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `$.removeAttr`, use `$.css` to restore the CSS.  `$.removeAttr` isn't going to work properly due to how CSS persists, most likely.

What you should really do is [add a class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) on focus, then [remove that class](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) on blur.  That is, `$.addClass` and `$.removeClass`, documented at the respective links.

Comment: No such luck I attempted to give it a class then remove it but the left border still stays.. I actually use the $.removeAttr in a few other places and it all renders fine. Funny that it doesn't for this situation.

Comment: I made a video demonstrating my problem 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCmYNOO5u4I

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
 - instead of removeAttr, reset the style with .css()
 - use a class instead, and use toggleClass() in the focus and our events

The second option is definitely preferable.

Comment: The issue remains using both options. I believe this is a CSS issue and not a javascript issue. I've sent my code to multiple friends and different computers and it works on FF and IE on all of theirs, but does this quirk on chrome.